# Is the following a Path?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

While watching a lecture on Eulerian path, I found the following slide
[image]

Now my question is how is the above walk a path? The vertex w is getting repeated twice and then $ue_1ve_2we_3xe_4ye_5w$ should be just a walk and not a path. Can anyone please help me with my erroneous concept?

Comment: Edges cannot be repeated.

Comment: But that is a trail

Comment: Yes, you could even just write the same without the vertices it is clearer

Comment: @JulesBesson No, like ny question is how is it a path w is repeated?

Comment: Why could you not pass two times by a same vertex?

Comment: In graph theory, a path in a graph is a finite or infinite sequence of edges which joins a sequence of vertices which, by most definitions, are all distinct. This is Wikipedia's version. It says all the vertices must be distinct.

Comment: @SarbanBhattacharya There is, unfortunately, another set of terminology, which uses "path" for what you'd call a "walk", and "simple path" for what you'd call a "path". It is less common these days, but sometimes it pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by the ordinary definitions a "Eulerian path" is usually not a "path". (Some sources might define "path" differently.) But "Eulerian path" is a common traditional term. Even though [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) uses mostly "Eulerian trail", the actual page title is "Eulerian path".

Comment: I'm not sure I would go by the choice of Wikipedia title in a question of mathematical history. The *very* traditional term is "Eulerian line", going back to Konig's graph theory textbook (in German), which you see in old papers such as [this one](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1942.11991280).